# combine assimp bone data with other vertex data

Tags: assimp

My problem is that I am trying to load in joint/bone data from an fbx file in Direct X c++ using Assimp, but I want to store the eights and indices inside the same vertex struct that I store position, uv, etc.

I can make a loop for every vertex, but I also want to make a loop over each bone.
That means I can't have both the joint data and the other data in the same loop.

Should I create multilpe vertec objects then combine them afterwards?

I also am not sure how to find the bone ID and the weight for each vertex, I am counting on 4 per bone, but maybe I should not have that last loop at all?
Im not sure how to set it up.

I would appreciate some help, thank you very much.

```
  for (UINT k = 0; k < currentMesh->mNumBones; k++)
    {

        aiBone* bone = currentMesh->mBones[k];

        for (UINT m = 0; m < bone->mNumWeights; m++)
        {
            aiVertexWeight weight = bone->mWeights[m];

            for (UINT n = 0; n < 4; n++)
            {
                //if




            }

        }




    }


     //////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (UINT k = 0; k < currentMesh->mNumVertices; k++)
    {



        Vertex vert;
        vert.position.x = currentMesh->mVertices[k].x;
        vert.position.y = currentMesh->mVertices[k].y;
        vert.position.z = currentMesh->mVertices[k].z;



        vert.TexCoord.x = currentMesh->mTextureCoords[0][k].x;
        vert.TexCoord.y = currentMesh->mTextureCoords[0][k].y;

        vert.normal.x = currentMesh->mNormals[k].x;
        vert.normal.y = currentMesh->mNormals[k].y;
        vert.normal.z = currentMesh->mNormals[k].z;





        vertexVector.push_back(vert);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (UINT k = 0; k < currentMesh->mNumBones; k++)
    {

        aiBone* bone = currentMesh->mBones[k];

        for (UINT m = 0; m < bone->mNumWeights; m++)
        {
            aiVertexWeight weight = bone->mWeights[m];


            if (vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].joints.x == 0)
            {
                vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].joints.x = k;
                vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].weights.x = weight.mWeight;
            }
            else if (vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].joints.y == 0)
            {
                vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].joints.y = k;
                vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].weights.y = weight.mWeight;
            }
            else if (vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].joints.z == 0)
            {
                vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].joints.z = k;
                vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].weights.z = weight.mWeight;
            }
            else if (vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].joints.w == 0)
            {
                vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].joints.w = k;
                vertexVector[weight.mVertexId].weights.w = weight.mWeight;
            }



        }




    }
```

I accessed the same structure I already have and added the stuff afterwards.